# $\sigma$-algebra generated by null sets

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A,P)$ a probability space and $N:=\{A\subseteq\Omega: \exists B\in\mathcal A: P(B)=0\land A\subseteq B\}$ the set of null sets. Let's consider the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $N$
$$\mathcal N:=\sigma(N).
$$
This is the completion of $\mathcal B:=\sigma(\{B\in\mathcal A: P(B)=0\})$. As $\mathcal B\subseteq\mathcal A$, we can restrict $P$ to $\mathcal B$ and by the construction of a complete measure we get a unique measure $P'$ on $\mathcal N$.

Does this $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal N$ only contain sets with $P'$-measure $0$ and $1$ or are there further sets contained? I'm asking this because $\sigma$-algebras have to contain complements and countable unions. But countable unions of null sets are null sets again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $\sigma(\mathcal{N})$ only has the sets of measure $0$ and $1$: the latter is a $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{N}$ so that's obvious.

Usually we consider the sigma algebra generated by $\mathcal{A} \cup \mathcal{N}$ which is the completion of $P$. Every set in it an be written as $A \cup N$ where $A \in \mathcal{A}$ and $N \in \mathcal{N}$ and we extend $P$ in the obvious way $P(A \cup N)= P(A)$ etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But there is still one point in your argumentation I can't follow completely. As I understand your argumentation, you use the fact that $\mathcal B$ contains only sets with $P$-measure $0$ and $1$. But how do we proof this? It seems totally reasonable, but I cann't see how to proof it.

Comment: @mag daw did did understand my argument: the set of all $0-1$ sets is a $\sigma$-algebra that contains $\mathcal{N}$ so also $\sigma(\mathcal{N})$.

Comment: Now I totally understand your argumentation. Thank you! But I think in your last comment the $\mathcal N$ sould be $N$ instead.

Comment: @mag minor point but yes.